# Flattening a nested record to its leaves

Tags: clojure

Note, I discovered a bug after I posted this. The current implementation drops any fields that have an associative value, which is not the intended behavior.

---

I'm writing a [Tamagotchi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamagotchi) clone, and need to be able to save the game's state to the disk. I want to save the entire state since it contains data other than the pet data like settings. Since de/serializing nested records is a pain, I decided to "flatten the nested records to their leaves". By that I mean if I have a record representing the game settings:

```
(defrecord Sim-Settings [health-per-tick pain-per-tick hunger-per-tick])
(defrecord Question-Settings [pain-per-wrong food-per-right])

(defrecord Settings [sim-settings question-settings])

(def test-settings
  (->Settings
    (->Sim-Settings 1 1 1)
    (->Question-Settings 1 1)))
```

I want to flatten that to:

```
(flatten-to-leaves test-settings)

{:health-per-tick 1,
 :pain-per-tick 1,
 :hunger-per-tick 1,
 :pain-per-wrong 1,
 :food-per-right 1}
```

All of the intermediate keys (`:sim-settings` and `question-settings`) are removed.

After struggling for a couple hours, I finally managed to get something working, but it's not perfect. All the solutions to similar problems I could find used `tree-seq`, which I had never used before. It's a cool function, but I'm afraid I might be forcing its usage here.

```
(defn flatten-to-leaves [record]
  (into {}

    (filter
      ; ... and filter out the non-leaves.
      #(and (map-entry? %)
            (not (associative? (second %))))

      ; Turn the record into a list of nodes of the map...
      (tree-seq associative? (partial apply list) record))))
```

Parts of it are nice. I like how `tree-seq` basically just turned this into a filtering problem.

My main problem is with the filtering function though. It is, I hate to admit, a product of fiddling. It works in every test case I've thrown at it, but something about it seems off. I have a feeling it can be reduced to something simpler.

I appreciate any critique regarding this code.

If I flatten the entire state:

```
(defrecord Pet [satiation max-satiation health max-health])
(defrecord Question-Generator [operator-ranges])
(defrecord Sim-Settings [health-per-tick pain-per-tick hunger-per-tick])
(defrecord Question-Settings [pain-per-wrong food-per-right])
(defrecord Settings [sim-settings question-settings])

(defrecord Game-State [pet q-gen last-update settings])
```

I get something like:

```
{:max-satiation 100,
 :hunger-per-tick 0.00347,
 :pain-per-tick 0.00347,
 :satiation 100,
 :pain-per-wrong 2,
 :max-health 100,
 :health-per-tick 0.0075,
 :last-update "20170905T204200.285Z",
 :food-per-right 5,
 :health 100}
```

Comment: To confirm, you're never going to have any overlapping leaf names?

Comment: @BenC I considered that, and no, I should never have duplicate keys. The design is pretty much done. I'm just finishing handling saving, and adding in a store system. That said though, I have a massive warning in the docs for the function reminding me of that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is good usage of `tree-seq`. It's intended for walking trees, right? If your settings will have ragged depth it's probably the cleanest approach.

The only main cleanup I see is that this predicate can be pointfree if you want:

```
#(and (map-entry? %)
      (not (associative? (second %))))
; =
(every-pred map-entry? (comp not associative? second))
```

On the other hand, I don't see a huge need for records here at all, as opposed to maps.

- Nested maps will de/serialize fine as-is with EDN (or JSON if there's nothing crazy in them)
- They're idiomatic across the Clojure community
- Define a clojure.spec spec for them if you want
- Records don't give you type safety anyway, and you're not using any of their class-abilities like extending protocols.
- Records are a bit faster if you're building thousands, but that doesn't look like the case here

Comment: Thanks. I considered getting rid of records entirely, but that seemed to be a much bigger undertaking. Maybe I'll try a project in the future where I only use bare maps, just to see how it turns out.